# Superclass and Subclasses in PHP

Tags: php, oop

Consider the following PHP class code

```
class SuperIdea{
.
.
.
static function getById($id){  new SuperIdea(.......); } 
.
.
.
.
}

class SubIdea extends SuperIdea{
}
```

The problem I face here is that when I call SubIdea::getbyId($t); the object returned is of type SuperIdea but I would like it to be of SubIdea.Is there any way to achieve it without repeating code in SubIdea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try replacing `new SuperIdea()` with `new {get_called_class()}();`

I've never tested this, but I see no reason why it shouldn't work...

Comment: Of note, `get_called_class` is new in PHP 5.3.

Comment: Any solution that can be used in PHP4 ?

Answer (score 2):

Ivar's answer (basically, to use get_called_class()) works.  Please upvote/select his answer.

Quick demo:

```
<?PHP
class supercls {
  static function foo(){
         $class = get_called_class();
         echo $class ."\n";
  }
}

class subcls extends supercls {

}

supercls::foo();
subcls::foo();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class SuperIdea {
    public $var;
    function __construct($var){
       $this->var = $var;
    }
    static function getById($id){  return new static('foobar'); } 
}

class SubIdea extends SuperIdea{}
var_dump(SubIdea::getById(0));
```

> object(SubIdea)#1 (1) {
>     ["var"]=>
>     string(6) "foobar"
>   }

PHP >= 5.3